# $5^n -4n-1$ is divisible by 16

Tags: induction

Checking the notes of a proof-based course I encountered this exercise. $5^n -4n-1$ is divisible by $16$ for every natural $n>0$.

I'm stuck with this problem. Help me, please

---

**Update**: I already solved this problem

Comment: Hint: $5^n=(4+1)^n$

Comment: Of course $0$ is divisible by $16$, so, the statement is true for $n=1$. Now suppose that the statement is true for some arbitrary $n$, and, with this, show that the statement is true for $n+1$.

Comment: **A Combinatorial Proof.**  Consider the set $S$ of arrays $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ where $x_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ such that there are at least two indices $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $x_k\neq 0$.  Let $f:S\to\{1,2,\ldots,n\}^2$ which sends each $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in S$ to  $(i,j)$, where $i$ and $j$ are the smallest indices $i$ and $j$ such that $i<j$, $x_i\neq 0$, and $x_j\neq 0$.  Prove  that the number of elements of $S$ which is mapped under $f$ to the same value $(i,j)\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}^2$ such that $i<j$ is a multiple of $16$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the step from $\;n\;$ to $\;n+1\;$ :

$$5^{n+1}-4(n+1)-1=5\cdot5^n-4n-4-1=(5^n-4n-1)+4\cdot5^n-4=$$

$$=(5^n-4n-1)+4\left(5^n-1\right)$$

All that is left to prove is that $\;5^n-1\;$ is divisible by $\;4\;$ , but

$$5^n-1=(5-1)(5^{n-1}+5^{n-2}\ldots+5^2+5+1)$$

Comment: I scratched out a proof similar to this one, but couldn't type quickly enough to post. The only difference was that I used saulspatz's hint to show $5^n-1=(4+1)^n-1$ is divisible by $4$. $(4+1)^n$ is a multiple of $4$ plus $1$, so ... ..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Use congruences: by *Euler's theorem*, the order of $5$ modulo $16$ is a divisor of $\varphi(16)=8$, and you readily can check it has order $4$. Also $4n\equiv 4\cdot (n\bmod 4) \mod{16}$ since $4^2\equiv 0\mod 16$.

Therefore you only have to check that $\;5^n -4n-1\equiv 0\mod 16$ for each of the congruence classes modulo $4$, i.e. for $n=0,1,2,3$.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative hint for the step from $n$ to $n+1$ in a proof by induction:**

$5^{n+1}-4(n+1)-1=5\cdot(5^n-4n-1)+16n$

Answer (score 0):

**Base case**: $n=1$
It's easy to see that $5^n -4n-1$ is divisible by $16$ because for $n=1$:
$$5^n -4n-1 = 5 - 4 - 1 = 0$$
and $0$ is divisible by $16$.

**Induction hypothesis**: assume now that $5^n -4n-1$ is divisible by $16$ for an arbitrary $n$

**Induction step**: prove that from the induction hypothesis it follows that $5^{(n+1)} -4(n+1)-1$ is divisible by $16$.

Since $5^n -4n-1$ is divisible by $16$ can write $5^n -4n-1 = 16k$ for some natural number $k>0$. This can be also written as (moving the $4n$ to the right):
$$5^n -1 = 16k +4n$$

Now $5^{(n+1)} -4(n+1)-1=5^{(n+1)} -4n -4 -1 = 5^{(n+1)} -4n -5 = 5(5^n)-4n-5 = 5(5^n-1)-4n$

But since by the induction hypothesis $5^n -1 = 16k +4n$ we can write:
$$5(5^n-1)-4n=5(16k +4n) -4n= 16(5k)+20n-4n=16(5k)+16n=16(5k+n)$$

which is a multiple of $16$.

Comment: Do you mean $5(n + 1)$ or $5^{n + 1}$ in your inductive step?

Comment: @an4s thanks for noticing! I forgot some ^s